# Go. Множественный вложенный вызов функций

Tags: golang

Допустим есть строка
`str := "    123455:foofoofoo    "` которую нужно обработать выполнив следующие действия:

1. Удалить пробелы вначале и конце
2. Получить строку после символа ":"
3. Заменить все foo -> bar

Как я выполняю эти операции сейчас:

```
st := "    123456:foofoofoo      "
repFoo := regexp.MustCompile("foo")
result := repFoo.ReplaceAllString(strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(st), ":")[1], "bar")
log.Println(result)
```

Я думал над следующими вариантами:

1. Каждое действие в отдельной переменной.
2. Создать функции для покрытия типовых действий над строками в своей программе с более короткими именами.
3. <strike>Оставить как есть</strike>

Меня интересует как более правильно структурировать код при изменении строк, когда требуется множество раз производить подобные манипуляции со строкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если все действо будет проходить в функции main, то плодить переменные точно не нужно. Если в отдельной функции, которая быстро отрабатывает, то для удобства можно - дело вкуса.
2. Если часто нужно делать такое преобразование, то делайте функции (или одну, если всегда преобразования одни и те же).
3. Если один раз нужно делать, то оставьте как есть. Единственно, регулярка для простой замены не нужна, лучше strings.Replace()
4. Если часто делаете преобразования строк, то можно создать свой тип.

Например:

```
type myString string

func (s myString) replace(old, new string) myString {
    return myString(strings.Replace(string(s), old, new, -1))
}
func (s myString) split(sep string, i int) myString {
    return myString(strings.Split(string(s), sep)[i])
}
func (s myString) trimSpace() myString {
    return myString(strings.TrimSpace(string(s)))
}

func main() {
    str := myString("    123455:foofoofoo    ")
    fmt.Println(str.replace("foo", "bar").split(":", 1).trimSpace())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/C-J3tnvNtYk